# Cloud functions with firestore cannot find any data

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am new to js and firestore (and the whole firebase eco-system)

I want to query data with 2 where fields (account_id, device_id) but I always get "No document found"

```
let selectQuery = admin.firestore().collection("devices");
    selectQuery.where("account_id", "==", context.auth.uid);
    selectQuery.where("device_id", "==", deviceId);

    selectQuery.get().then(function(doc) {
        if (doc.exists) {
            console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
        } else {
            // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
            console.log("No such document!");
        }
        return "asd";
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting document:", error);
    });
```

I even tried removing the where clauses however the data still cannot be found but it's there:

[image]

The parameter from context and data are
// UID = UIDwFK2JVghw8XjVGqlEE0Uj09irGK2
// DEVICE_ID = 552cbe50f935de7a

As request here is the full code:

```
exports.authDevice = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    if (!context.auth) {
        // Throwing an HttpsError so that the client gets the error details.
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('failed-precondition', 'The function must be called ' +
            'while authenticated.');
    }

    const deviceName = data.device_name;
    const deviceId = data.device_id;
    const isQR = data.is_qr;
    const uid = context.auth.uid;

    console.log("DEVICE NAME: " + deviceName);
    console.log("DEVICE ID: " + deviceId);
    console.log("is QR: " + isQR);
    console.log("UID: " + uid);

    admin.firestore().collection("devices")
        .where("account_id", "==", context.auth.uid)
        .where("device_id", "==", deviceId)
        .get().then(function(doc) {
        if (doc.exists) {
            console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
        } else {
            // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
            console.log("No such document!");
        }
        return "asd";
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting document:", error);
    });
});
```

Comment: I think you should be chaining the calls together: `let selectQuery = admin.firestore().collection("devices").where("account_id", "==", context.auth.uid).where("device_id", "==", deviceId);` - but I'd still expect it to show data as-is, just without any filtering.

Comment: According to https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries section: Invalid: Range filters on different fields
show that this is the way it should not be used

Comment: Good catch, they indeed need to be chained together: `admin.firestore().collection("devices").where("account_id", "==", context.auth.uid).where("device_id", "==", deviceId).get().then(function(doc) {...`

Comment: @user93466: But you haven't got range filters. You've got two equality filters. Look at the first example for compound queries: `citiesRef.where('state', '==', 'CO').where('name', '==', 'Denver');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some debuging I found that it does not return a single document but a "QUERY SNAPSHOT" which has method empty or size.

After the change:

```
return admin.firestore().collection("devices").where("account_id", "==", context.auth.uid)
        .where("device_id", "==", deviceId).get().then((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
        });
        console.log("Empty: " + snapshot.empty);
        console.log("Size: " + snapshot.size);
        return "asd"
    })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log('Error getting documents', err);
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

The `context.auth` is only available for realtime database triggered functions. From the [documentation for the `EventContext.auth` parameter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.EventContext#.auth):

> Authentication information for the user that triggered the function. This object contains uid and token properties for authenticated users. For more detail including token keys, see the security rules reference.
>
> For an unauthenticated user, this field is `null`. **For event types that do not provide user information (all except Realtime Database) or for Firebase admin users, this field will not exist.**

Comment: Hey, context.auth is not null/undefined - all data is there (I did a console.log) and everything is the way it should be

Comment: And also this is not realtime database trigger but a onCall trigger - https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable

Comment: Please update your question to include that information.